# Not running the same command twice or more in execvp

Tags: c, execvp

I'm using execvp to execute some commands like ls -l, who, cp -r ./aaa ./bbb etc. Everything is ok until I try to execute the same command for the second time. For example I will show you the order I use:ls -l (everything is fine), who (everything is fine), ls -l(bad address). This is my code:

```
if(strcmp(com_instr, "issuejob") == 0)
{
        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {           
            perror("Fork");
            exit(1);
        }

        else if(pid == 0)
        {                   
            sleep(0.1);

            //number of args
            read(fd, &t_args, sizeof(int));

            printf("t_args %d\n",t_args);

            commands = malloc(t_args*sizeof(char *));

            for(i=0; i<t_args; i++)
            {
                commands[i] = malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
            }   

            for(i=0; i<t_args; i++)
            {
                read(fd, commands[i], SIZE);
            }               

            //Receiving data from named-pipe

            /*temp_run = run_node->next;
            while(temp_run != NULL)
            {
                printf("jjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjj %d",temp_run->job_id);
                temp_run = temp_run->next;
            }*/

            printf("command %s\n", commands[0]);        
            execvp(commands[0], commands);
            perror("execvp");
            exit(1);
        }

        else if(pid > 0)
        {
            temp_run = run_node; 
            for(i=0; i<run_num; i++)
            {
                if(temp_run->next != NULL) temp_run = temp_run->next;
                else break;                 
            }

            if((i <= run_num-1) && (wait_node->next == NULL))
            {
                temp_run->next = malloc(sizeof(run_list));
                temp_run = temp_run->next;
                saving_data_run(temp_run, j_id, line, 1, arg_num-1, pid);
                printf("pid:%d\n",temp_run->pid);
                ++running;
                send_data_for_exec(line, arg_num-1, fd);
            }

            else
            {
                temp_wait = wait_node;
                while(temp_wait->next != NULL) temp_wait = temp_wait->next;
                temp_wait->next = malloc(sizeof(wait_list));
                saving_data_wait(temp_wait, j_id, line, 0, arg_num-1, pid);
                wait_num++;
            }

        }

    j_id++;
}
```

I use named pipes to pass my args in a char **commands. Args are passing correctly to char **commands, I have checked that with printf. Is there any problem executing the same command more than one time , in execvp? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I assume you fork first, since execvp replaces the calling process with the new program? The problem might be related to the fork. It would make it a lot easier for us if you could provide a complete, minimal example that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: Yeah I use fork(). I will try to edit it.

Comment: Please provide a [complete, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's often easier to spot the problem by running your program and seeing where it crashes than by staring at the code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm concerned about your use of:

```
        for(i=0; i<t_args; i++)
        {
            read(fd, commands[i], SIZE);
        }
```

That's going to always read in size bytes from your file (or pipe?), every time you call read.  It may be that your file is constructed correctly, but I'm wondering if you're accidentally pulling in too much data in these read commands.

For example, if your file / pipe was filled with the following:

2, 'l', 's', ' ', '-', 'l', '\0', 1, 'c', 'd', '\0', 2, 'l', 's', ' ', '-', 'l', '\0'

And SIZE were #define'd to be 80, then on your first call you'd read in 2 into t_args, but your first read could consume the rest of the data into commands[0].  The second read to commands[1] 
would have no data in it.

Its not clear from your description what your data looks like... might be a good idea to print it out in a loop byte by byte, after each read call, along with the return value of read.  Typically read will return to you the number of bytes actually read... you can use this to help sanity check your answer.

Hope that helps,
- J.